# Что такое сокеты в unix и как посмотреть их в ОС?

Tags: сеть, сокет, unix, сокеты

Много информации в интернете, что такое сокет, типа абстракция для межпроцессного взаимодействия, что на сервере создается сокет и к нему привязывается ip и порт, при новом подключении клиента создается копия сокета, у сокета есть дескриптор, так где посмотреть этот дескрипторов? Больше  числа fd не получится сделать подключений к серверу? Сокету это структура в оперативной памяти?

Comment: С чтения [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81)) (далее рекурсивно) начать  пробовали?

Comment: Читал, для меня не столь очевидно все! Не стал бы сюда писать, гуглить умею. Может посоветуете какую нибудь лабу, книгу, чтобы понять сокеты глубже или как для чайников объяснить что из себя они представляют.

Comment: Например, [книга](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~jbreecher/cs280/UNIX%20Network%20Programming(Volume1,3rd).pdf), а вот  [Linux Socket (network) programming tutorial](https://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html) / imho почитав и попробовав exemples все станет понятно. Если совсем коротко, то сокет это файловый дескриптор, который можно читать и в него же писать для обмена с другим процессом (в т.ч. по сети)